# Why my keyboard take this background color on Dark mode?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, mobile, xamarin.ios

[This is my keyboard on dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQyeU.png)

I'm using this:

`field.KeyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark;`

Update:
You have to set your background view

```
view.backgroundColor = .black //(for dark mode)

view.backgroundColor = .white //(for light mode)
```

Xamarin.iOS

```
View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black; //(for dark mode)

View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White; //(for light mode)
```

Comment: Maybe I did not understand correctly
You have set the keyboard background color in the dark and according to the image, the keyboard is in the dark mode correctly

Comment: Yes, but I want my keyboard have black background like WhatsApp keyboard that it's black not Gray.
Can you understand my point?

Like this images: 
[ https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/10/1540215972_whatsapp_dark_mode_story.jpg ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd saw your image on comments and I notice why your keyboard seems more "whiter" than WhatsApp keyboard. Its because WhatsApp background is black and our iOS Keyboard is translucent.

Try to set your background to black

```
view.backgroundColor = .black
```

And see whats happen! I hope helped you

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO !

Apple design that **[UIKeyboardAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyboardappearance?language=objc)** has four types , and each type has its feature .

- **UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault**
  : Specifies the default keyboard appearance for the current input method. This constant corresponds to the 
  UIKeyboardAppearanceLight
  value.
- **UIKeyboardAppearanceDark**
  : Specifies a keyboard appearance suitable for a dark UI look.
- **UIKeyboardAppearanceLight**
  : Specifies a keyboard appearance suitable for a light UI look.
- **UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert**
  : Specifies a keyboard appearance suitable for an alert panel.

Therefore , the keyboard will show the dark background when setting

```
field.KeyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But I want my keyboard looks like WhatsApp keyboard with black background.

See this image: [https://cdn.neow.in/news/images/uploaded/2018/10/1540215972_whatsapp_dark_mode_story.jpg]

Comment: @clarencemontenegro Okey , glad found the solution !